# RemoteConfigRealtimeService.StreamFetchInvalidations errors on Firebase Remote Config Realtime API

Tags: android, ios, swift, firebase, firebase-remote-config

I cannot find a single online reference to explain the RemoteConfigRealtimeService.StreamFetchInvalidations errors that are appearing on the Firebase Remote Config Realtime API.

I assume these errors are related to why real time remote config is not working as expected in my apps. Sometimes it works; sometimes it doesn't. I'm not able to identify a pattern of how and why it works.

I use remote config mainly to enable/disable game options (buttons) in my IOS and Android apps.

The normal/initial fetchAndActivate works as expected. When the apps load, the active remote config settings are applied. But, if I change a setting after an app has opened, sometimes the updated settings will be recognized, but most times they don't. I'm assuming this StreamFetchInvalidations explains the "why", but I have not been able to find any documentation that explains this error.

Does anyone have any insights into causes of these errors and how to address them?

Updated:

I think I'm on the track to resolve this. It appears that things are a bit wonky in how I tried to restrict the Firebase API keys. When I removed all restrictions from the key, things started working as expected (although there is a longer than desired delay). For the time-being, I am going to leave the key unrestricted while I try to expand my understanding of defining those restrictions. Also, I DID find the LogCat warnings; I had been filtering them out. Newbie mistake - SMH